# Превью в виде картинки из файла MS Word

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, понадобилось сделать превью вордовского файла в виде картинки, что б еще сохранялось форматирование текста.

Например как тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая задача встает впервые, посоветуйте с чего начать изучение данной задачи. Желательно, даже очень, что б это было средствами PHP. Может есть библиотеки какие, или статьи у кого нибудь в закладках.

Comment: с какого ресурса скрин?

Comment: a-center.ru, но такое везде где курсачи и дипломы

Comment: да и даже почтовые сервисы, типа gmail, mail и т.д. делают превью загруженного файла

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/264443/)

Comment: да я читал это статью, с++ или с# зашел бы еще, но не qt

Comment: а если прочитать файл, а потом на основе его параметров создать png, средствами php картинку с текстом? А и забыл написать, COM не подходит, т.к. работать должно под линуксом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как сделать без сторонних утилит не знаю, но может быть подойдет такое решение.

- ставим libreoffice (или open - значения не имеет): **sudo apt-get install libreoffice**
- ставим imagemagick (либо расширением к пыху): **sudo apt-get install imagemagick**
- конвертим doc в pdf: **lowriter --convert-to pdf test.doc**
- конвертим 1ю страницу pdf в картинку: **convert test.pdf[0] test.jpg**

из php ко всем этим командам можно обращаться через shell_exec. 
как-то так ^_^

Comment: то что надо, идеально)